# Does server produce a socket listening on a randomly available port for every request?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

My question is regarding the port used by `clientSocket`.
The docs referenced above say that the client gets a randomly available port number while the server's socket (line 2 above):

> When a connection is requested and successfully established, the
>   accept method returns a new Socket object which is bound to the same
>   local port and has its remote address and remote port set to that of
>   the client.

But isn't the server's port number being used already by the `ServerSocket` for listening to requests?
If the same port is used by the server for serving requests too, then how do the multiple sockets (Line 1 and 2 in above code) know which request is for which socket?

Comment: That's just how it works - the operating system takes care of dispatching new inbound connections to the listening server socket and then subsequently exchanging data on the sockets returned by `accept`.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak, I was hoping if someone could provide me a link to some code or a blog, book etc that sheds a little more details on `just how it works` :)